# When I use scale CSS function about a element, its text size is changed though its font-size is the same. I want to keep the text size after rescaling

Tags: jquery, css

What is the problem is I should use scale CSS function in my project. In this case, I want to keep text-size.

```
trSel.css('transform', 'scale(0.8, 1) translateX(-50px)');
trSel.css('font-size', '2vw');
```

Comment: If you want to keep the same font-size you shouldn't use `vw` probably `px` should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's not logically possible** to keep your actual text size as is if you are applying `transform: scale(...);` to the container/parent element. CSS transform makes direct changes to the physical coordinates of the specified element - which forces the scaling of length units as well.

If you want to maintain the same text size, you should just scale your parent element using width/height, or, apply **reverse scaling** to your text element.

For example:

```html
<div class="parent" style="transform: scale(2)">
   <p class="text" style="transform: scale(0.5)">
      The actual text size of this paragraph will remain as is.
   </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Addition to accepted answer. Good example here:

```
main {
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 100px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: all 4s;
  color: black;
}

body:hover .animate-one {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.animate-element p {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: all 4s;
}

body:hover .animate-element {
  transform: scale(2);
}

body:hover .animate-element p {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

<body>
  <main>
   <div class="animate-element">
     <p>Animate scale</p>
   </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mhre9b0u/3/